# Incuding a web application in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have a Joomla site and was asked to include an application in it. The application has its own index.php, htaccess, databases etc. Just adding the application files and merging the two index.php brakes both the site and the app. The index.php of the application sets the rules of how it works and it can't without it. Is there a sure-fire way to merge them without touching one another?

**index.php(application)**

```
<?php

session_start();
$all_url = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url = explode('/', $all_url[0]);

//Homepage
if (empty($url[1])) {
$url[1] = '/frontpage';
}

$tpl = 'home';

$config = array(
'host' => 'xxx', //CHANGE THIS, DB SERVER
'user' => 'xxx', //CHANGE THIS, DB USER
'password' => 'xxx', //CHANGE THIS, DB PASSWORD
'database' => 'xxx' //CHANGE THIS, DB NAME
);
$DB = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['database'], $config['user'], $config['password']);
$DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$DB->exec("SET names utf8");

if (file_exists('controller/' . $url[1] . '.php')) {

$gtpl = 'main';
$restricted = array('cart');

if (!isset($_SESSION['firstVisit']) && $url[1]!='frontpage') {
    $_SESSION['firstVisit'] = false; //ensures we never enter this clause again
    require 'controller/frontpage.php';
}else if (empty($_SESSION['uid']) && in_array($url[1], $restricted)) {
    //not logged in, but trying to access restricted page.
    require 'controller/login.php';
}else{
    require 'controller/' . $url[1] . '.php';
}

$path = (empty($_GET["custom"])) ? 'view/' . $gtpl . '.php' : $gtpl;

require $path;

} else {
echo 'ERROR - File not found!!!';

}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to start developing a small component which imports your application.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "Wrapper" menu type you can create a menu item that loads this application wrapped within an iframe.